# Java: Widening and autoboxing conversion issue

Tags: java, type-conversion

I don't get why java doesn't do the widening and then autoboxing.

```
Integer i = (short) 10;
```

I would think the following would take place:

1. Narrowing conversion first from `10` to `short`.
2. `short` would then widen to `int`.
3. `int` would then autobox to `Integer`.

Instead it's a compilation error.

Example 2:

Short x = 10;
Integer y = x;

This fail too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [JLS, Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), which deals with *assignment conversion*:

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening
>     reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

It is unable to apply two conversions at once (widening primitive conversion and boxing conversion); only one conversion can apply here, so it has to result in an error.

The solution would be to cast the `short` back to an `int` (a casting conversion), which would allow the assignment conversion to be a boxing conversion:

```
Integer i = (int) (short) 10;
```

(Or here, don't cast it to `short` in the first place.)

```
Integer i = 10;
```

Comment: Based on JLS 5.1.5, why my example 2 fail?

Comment: When dealing with the wrapper objects such as `Short` and `Integer`, it's important to realize that a `Short` is _not_ an `Integer`; one does not subclass the other.  The conversion that you reference here (Widening Reference Conversion) is not applicable here.

Comment: Oh yes. I remember now. Widening reference conversion involves subclasses - in other words classes which are related. Thx

Answer (score 3):

What's going on here is a casting conversion from `int` to `short`, and then an attempted assignment conversion from `short` to `Integer`.

Assignment conversion ([§5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) allowed for boxing and then widening, but not widening and then boxing.

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening
>     reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

Comment: why not int to short and then to int and then only to Integer? Not intelligent enough? :OP

Comment: @yapkm01 It's not that the JVM isn't intelligent enough, it's that it's simply not allowed. `short` to `int` is a widening primitive conversion and `int` to `Integer` is a boxing conversion. Assignment conversion can only perform one of those two operations, not both.

Answer (score 0):

IN java it follows sequence as "autoBoxing and then widening" only no matter if you are doing
this :
int x =5;
Object obj = x;

Or
this:

int x = 5;
Long l = x;

Widening occurs only when there is a is-a relationship.
So while applying above sequence first case is very much valid for compiler, because int would be autobox to Integer and then assigned to Object, i.e. widening (i.e. autobox first and then widening), being in Is-A relationship. But in second case if int x is autbox to Integer and the assign to Long it will not be allowed, being not is-a relationship, hence throws compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Could simulate the similar use case using overloading with respect to autoboxing and widening.

```
public static void m(short s) {
    System.out.println("widening");
  }

public static void m(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("Autoboxing");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    short x = 10;
    m(x);
}
```

**Output:** widening

Hence, in nut shell we could say, **Widening dominates Autoboxing in java**